# Ruby Fog gem usage

Tags: ruby, fog

I'm mucking about with the Fog gem and have figured out how to get started:

```
1.9.3-p545 :008 > c = Fog::Compute::Ecloud.new({
1.9.3-p545 :009 >       :base_path => '/cloudapi/spec',
1.9.3-p545 :010 >       ecloud_authentication_method: 'basic_auth',
1.9.3-p545 :011 >       ecloud_username: 'user@terremark.com',
1.9.3-p545 :012 >       ecloud_password: 'password'
1.9.3-p545 :013?>     })
[fog][WARNING] Unrecognized arguments: base_path
 => #<Fog::Compute::Ecloud::Real:25681720 @base_path="/cloudapi/spec" @connections={} @connection_options={} @host="https://services.enterprisecloud.terremark.com" @persistent=false @version="2013-06-01" @authentication_method=:basic_auth @access_key=nil @private_key=nil @username="user@terremark.com" @password="password">
```

I don't know what to do after this, though. How do I get the object to do anything useful? I'm new to Ruby so a lot of the code in the [Fog Ecloud source](https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/master/lib/fog/ecloud/compute.rb) doesn't make sense to me.

I've tried using different methods, but each tends to result in an error.

Can someone provide an example and explanation indicating where I need to go from here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have found a bug!

Fog is giving you this error because `base_url` is not present in the `recognizes` [line](https://github.com/fog/fog/blob/master/lib/fog/ecloud/compute.rb#L15-L17).

I went ahead and fixed it for you. If you are using bundler you can use the latest master by updating your `Gemfile` to include the following

`gem 'fog', :git => 'https://github.com/fog/fog.git'`

Or alternatively you can just patch it in your code by executing the following code prior to using fog

```
require 'fog'
module Fog
  module Compute
    class Ecloud < Fog::Service
      recognizes :ecloud_username, :ecloud_password, :ecloud_version,
                 :ecloud_access_key, :ecloud_private_key,
                 :ecloud_authentication_method, :base_path 
    end
  end
end
```

For information about how to use fog, I would recommend reading the following [page](http://fog.io/compute/).

Comment: Yup, that fixed it. I had previously looked at the page you linked to. Unfortunately, as new as I am to Ruby and with as little documentation for the ecloud provider as there is, I'm not able to piece together how to move forward. I can sort out the methods available with `c.methods`, but when I attempt to execute one I get `ArgumentError: wrong number of argumetns (# for #)`. How do I sort out which arguments are necessary for each method? It's all rather confusing and that webpage only provides a very brief synopsis while the ecloud provider has pretty much no documentation.

Comment: Additionally, utilizing the interactive `fog` shell doesn't help because neither `ecloud` nor `terremark` are recognized providers.